# Cloud SQL (SQL Server 2017) connecting with SSMS, is it possible?

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-sql

I can't connect with SSMS to Google Cloud SQL Server 2017 despite having the IP address added?

When attempting to connect I receive standard:

> Cannot connect to xxxx
>   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Access is denied.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5)
>    (...)
>   Access is denied

Comment: For some reason i can't edit your question to make it well formatted (I get *"**An error occurred submitting the edit.**"*). Perhaps someone else could have a go.

Comment: I think the best solution for you is to contact support and ask for help. This is not really a problem the SO community can solve. Even if we had credentials to test, it would be off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about troubleshooting a paid SaaS service and not related to programming.

Comment: Hi All, there aren't many KB articles on this as it's only BETA, "http://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/external-connection-methods" which where I should normally find the details returns 404. I simply wanted to get a guidance on the subject of connecting to the SQL DB in Gcloud via SSMS

Comment: I have the same issue, according to google docs me and my teams need to install `gcloud` but we prefer not to. Is there any way to just login via local ssms and using public IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the inconvenience on that missing page, which is likely due to the beta docs still rolling out. Can you let me know where you linked from to get that 404, so that I can make sure we fix it?

For an example of how to connect SSMS to SQL Server in a Cloud SQL instance, check out the [Quickstart for Cloud SQL with SQL Server](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/quickstart). Connecting via the Cloud SQL proxy as shown there is the recommended approach, and you can find more info about how to do that in my blog post on [Managing SQL Server instances in Cloud SQL](https://medium.com/google-cloud/managing-sql-server-instances-in-cloud-sql-ecee1e48aa4e). Let me know if you have questions.